# Uno: Infrared Transmitter Module Not Transmitting

Tags: arduino-uno, infrared

I purchased https://www.jaycar.co.nz/medias/sys_master/images/images/9677365510174/XC4426-dataSheetMain.pdf, which seems identical to https://arduinomodules.info/ky-005-infrared-transmitter-sensor-module/.

I connected the module according to the diagram:
[image]

I then copied the following Sketch:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial interface
}
void loop() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
       irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12); // code for Sony TV power command
       delay(5000); // wait 5 seconds
   }
}
```

When I compiled the above, I got the following warning:

> warning: 'void IRsend::sendSony(long unsigned int, int)' is deprecated: This old function sends MSB first! Please use sendSony(aAddress, aCommand, aNumberOfRepeats).

So, I modified the code and added a `3` for the `aNumberOfRepeats` parameter. Thus, my final Sketch was this:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial interface
}
void loop() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
       irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12, 3); // code for Sony TV power command
       delay(5000); // wait 5 seconds
   }
}
```

When I ran the Sketch on my Uno and viewed the module through my camera phone, I did not see the module blinking. My assumption is that this is not working for some reason. Any ideas why?

Also, I'm measuring about 4.5 volts between GND and the middle pin. That seems right. When I measure GND and the signal out pin, I get a steady 0.64 volts. Shouldn't that be toggling between 0 and some number?

**UPDATE per @orithena's comment:**

I've updated the code as per suggested, but the transmitter still doesn't blink when viewed through my camera phone:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

IRsend irsend;

#define IR_SEND_PIN 5

void setup()
{
    pinMode(IR_SEND_PIN , OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
       irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12, 255);
       delay(1000);
   }
}
```

Just a few notes about this new code:

1. I tested connecting `S` to pins 3 and 5; neither worked
2. `255` is the highest number I could set for `aNumberOfRepeats`, otherwise I would get a compile warning: "warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type"

**UPDATE per @jsotola's comment:**

[image][image][image]

Comment: It may be that everything is blinking too fast for you to see or measure. Or, your pin 3 may be broken. Try explicitely initializing the pin: `pinMode(3, OUTPUT);` in setup. Try changing the signal pin: insert `#define IR_SEND_PIN 5` at the very top of your sketch and connect S to pin 5. Try increasing the number of repeats to 1000, so that the LED blinks longer.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: Why are you using `0xa90` as Sony remote address, and `12` as command code? See the [example](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/examples/SendDemo/SendDemo.ino#L235-L248) code for Sony remote control. If you are not sure, run [MinimalReceiver](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/examples/MinimalReceiver/MinimalReceiver.ino) and point your remote to the arduino to decode the IR code, and then use it for your IR_send sketch.

Comment: On your updated code, if you explicitly `#define IR_SEND_PIN 5;`, then your pinMode() function should be `pinMode(IR-SEND_PIN, OUTPUT)`. Don't just copy and paste the code, try to understand the code.

Comment: why did you connect the 5 V ? ... that module uses only two pins ... it needs only data and ground connections

Comment: @jsotola the diagram I followed connected all three pins.

Comment: @hcheung I don't care what signal I'm sending. I just want to see a signal to be sent. I'm not seeing anything through my camera phone. Also, I did use `pinMode(IR_SEND_PIN, OUTPUT)`  in one of my tests (when I connected to pin 5; it didn't work.

Comment: the crazy part is that you are wasting your time with arduino programming ... all you have to do, is to connect the module to a 5 V power supply and it should light up

Comment: please post clear, well lit pictures of the front and back of the IR emitter module ... I have a suspicion that a component is missing from it

Comment: @jsotola - I tried attaching the transmitter to GND and 5V only (no programming). I still don't see anything thought the camera phone. Would that suggest that the device is defective? Also - see photos in my post per your request.

Comment: the pictures are not very clear ... it looks like a resistor may be missing ... it is quite possible that the the board is incomplete

Comment: @jsotola - The operating voltage of the infrared transmitter module is 5VDC. No need for a resistor, right?

Comment: Hooking an IRED/LED directly to a voltage source is a time-honoured way of creating Dark Emitting Diode.

Comment: It really looks like R1 is missing. And yes, the operating voltage of the whole module is 5V -- the (typically) 1.5V forward voltage of the IR Diode is reached in a 5V circuit by using a 220Ohm resistor. Therefore, changing the resistor changes the operating voltage of the module. And: if it is missing, there is no electrical connection from the module's signal pads to the LED itself, so the LED cannot turn on.

Comment: I'll get another transmitter in case I now have a "Dark Emitting Diode", @timemage. Where would I connect R1, @orinthena?

Comment: Someone can tell you about IREDs/LEDs generally, but it's not really a good answer to the question. It would a better answer if someone could answer with some certainty about how your particular boards are made. The best resources I can find on the design of that board are very poor. If I had one, I would use a meter to determine the exact nature of the board before writing an answer. So far the only one here known to have this board is you. So the question seems mostly answerable (well) by you, so far anyway.

Comment: @ArduinoNewbie On the pads marked with R1... well, scratch that. I just devoted an hour finding more info on the KY-005 module. I found it to be one of the most underdocumented module I've ever seen. It seems to have a place for a resistor to solder in, but thats not documented anywhere except in some reverse engineering blog (also, if you solder one in, use the middle pin instead of S). Its sold everywhere listed with an operating voltage of 5V, but without R1, it'd be at most 1.5V. It's just an IR LED soldered to a PCB. Better unsolder the LED and use it directly (with 220Ohm resistor).

Comment: Although you might've run into the "Dark Emitting Diode" problem already, since I'm now pretty sure that you did put the full 5V onto the IR LED (that module is just bad: every shop tells you "it's for 5V! put it on your Arduino!" when the resistor is missing that should reduce the 5V to 1.5V). It may be that the LED is now shorting your Arduino pin to GND, so that pin may have taken some damage. Try another pin (don't forget to adapt the software to use another pin!) when you try a new IR LED.